# Dont see why this linear algebra equation is correct

Tags: linear-algebra, regression, bayesian

From the wikipedia page on [Bayesian Linear Regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_linear_regression)

A prior $\rho(\beta, \sigma^2)$ is conjugate to this likelihood function if it has the same functional form with respect to $\beta$ and $\sigma$. Since the log-likelihood is quadratic in $\beta$, the log-likelihood is re-written such that the likelihood becomes normal in $(\beta - \hat{\beta})$. Write

$$
(\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{X}\beta)^T (\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{X}\beta) = (\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{X} \hat{\beta})^T (\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{X}\hat{\beta}) + (\beta - \hat{\beta}) \mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X} (\beta - \hat{\beta})
$$

It kind of just throws this out without showing why it is true.

Answer (score 1):

First do a Taylor expansion (the function is quadratic in $\beta$):
$$
(y-X\beta)^T(y-X\beta) = (y-X\hat\beta)^T(y-X\hat\beta) 
+ 2 (y-X\hat\beta)^TX(\beta-\hat \beta) + (\beta-\hat\beta)^TX^TX(\beta-\hat\beta).$$
Since $\hat\beta$ satisfies $X^TX\beta = X^Ty$, the middle term vanishes.
This is because $\hat\beta$ is a least-squares solution, i.e., it solves
$$
\min_\beta (y-X\beta)^T(y-X\beta)
$$